# Unable to connect to postgres instance when flask app Dockerfile in different directory

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a project structure like this

```
project-root/
    back/
        Dockerfile
   docker-compose.yaml
    .env
```

Where `docker-compose.yaml` has

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/posgresql/data      

  flask_app:
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: ./back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${FLASK_PORT}:${FLASK_PORT}
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: "development"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
```

And my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP=main.py

CMD if [ "$FLASK_ENV" = "development" ]; then flask --debug run; else flask run; fi
```

and .env

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
FLASK_PORT=5000
```

But my flask app is unable to connect to postgres with the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Regular python scripts ran from my host like seed scripts and integration tests are able to connect to postgres with no problem. And when I move everything under `/back` the flask app within docker can connect as well. But I would like `docker-compose.yaml`
to live in the project root so I can build out a frontend and connect all the pieces together.

There must be some docker compose networking piece that I haven't been able to figure out.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `network_mode: host` line for your Flask application and use `postgres` as the database host provided in your Flask application, as according to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) :

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.

By default, the container's name is the name of the `service`, but you can override this behavior using [container_name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name).

Keep in mind that `localhost` should only be used when you're trying to reach containers from your host machine, as long as you've exposed the ports of the container. Otherwise containers can join each other using `container_name`.